# convert lambdas into method refrences

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of gadgets.

```
List<String> gadgets = new ArrayList<>(); 

gadgets.add("SmartPhone"); 
gadgets.add("SmartWatch");
gadgets.add("SmartTV"); 
gadgets.add("SmartDoor"); 
gadgets.add("iPhone");
```

I want to convert the below code into method reference, right now it consists of lambda expressions. Please advise how can I convert this into method reference

```
String myItem = gadgets.stream()
                       .peek(s -> System.out.println("processing: " + s)) 
                       .filter(s -> s.length() > 8)
                       .findFirst()
                       .orElse(""); 

System.out.println("result: " + myItem);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move your code into methods:

```
private void accept(String s) {
    System.out.println("processing: " + s);
}

private boolean test(String s) {
    return s.length() > 8;
}
```

And then:

```
String myItem = gadgets
        .stream()
        .peek(YourClass::accept)
        .filter(YourClass::test)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse("");
```

In such cases I recommend to stick with lambda. Just format your code like above and lambda will be readable.

Answer (score 0):

you can't to that here, as you have additional logic, like  `"processing: " + s` and `> 8`. If you will remove it - it could be changed to : `.peek(System.out::println)`.

Another way is to wrap logic into separate methods, like:

```
public boolean isLengthMoreThan8(String s){
return s.length > 8
}
```

and use method reference:

```
.filter(this::isLengthMoreThan8)...
```